# Mega-menu - Cannot select child elements on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in the process of adapting a pretty stunning looking bootstrap mega menu into a fully responsive version. I wish to keep the look and feel of the menu as it is very eye-catching however the menu currently makes use of Bootstrap's dropdown-menu functionality meaning the user must click to reveal the menu. In my eyes this is not a good user experience on the desktop as many will expect a menu to appear on hover. So, I have adapted the menu using the following code to ensure the child elements of the mega menu are shown when the user hovers over an element on the desktop:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .mega-dropdown:hover .mega-dropdown-menu{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This is great and achieves the desired effect of revealing the menu on hover on a desktop however when I move the mouse to select menu items, the menu disappears. I believe this is because of the gap that is present between the link that triggers the child menu and top of the child menu.

[image]

Is there any way in which I can cause the menu to stay open long enough for the user to move into the child menu using just HTML and CSS? I know I could easily use Javascript for this but in my eyes Javascript should be used sparingly and only when really necessary.

Full code can be found in this Codepen:

http://codepen.io/JasonEspin/pen/zGqoBa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the top margin and replace it with something you can actually over over like a transparent border.

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0; /* remove applied top margin */
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

Note: I've not tested this at other widths to you would have so test if this is what is required at **all** widths.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LVNJPy)

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D. A great CSS only solution with an actual code example.

Comment: It's not perfect so you may need to tweak. Note how you've lost the top corner border-radius..oh, and the slight grey border on the top is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I've set another alternative using a div with fixed position above the element of the dropdown and using the same z-index as the menu. In my case i only used css and no js at all.

```
positon:fixed;
z-index:10;
```

here's the example [image: here]